# Eclipse Not Working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Actually I downloaded the Android SDK from their site it was a bundle for android development and it was working fine. Then I downloaded the Netbeans from Java official site. It said it requires JDK7 so I downloaded that too. Now the Net Beans is working fine but eclipse displays this really long message box saying that Java was started but returned exit code 1 and then followed by some gibberish

My eclipse configuration file has the following text in it:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Comment: I think you must read the gibberish (and show us the important part of it here ). Often the solution is in there in plain text ...

Comment: Thanks But I installed the Jre7 it said it is already installed so do you want to re install it? and I said yes. After that the Problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Add **'-XX:-UseCompressedOops'** to the  **eclipse.ini**